# redirectioning printf to pipe C

Tags: c, linux, printf, pipe

The code above does not give any warnings or errors, but the parent does not print the string passed with the pipe. Any idea?

```
pid_t pid;
int fd[2];
int num_bytes_read;
char buffer[80];
pipe (fd);
pid=fork();
if (pid == 0) {/*Son*/
    fclose(stdout);
    close(fd[0]);
    dup(fd[1]);
    printf ("write in pipe\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}
else { /*Parent*/
    close (fd[1]);
    num_bytes_read = read (fd[0], buffer, sizeof (buffer));
    printf ("The received string is: %s\n", buffer);
}
return (0);
```

Comment: Try to use `close(1);` instead of `fclose(stdout);`

Comment: Fyi this depends on the C library you're using - on musl it works as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the child you are writing to FILE* which you have just closed (i.e. stdout). With dup you have assigned to fd == 0 the descriptor of the pipe, but the structure where `stdout` points remains "closed". Either write to pipe using write (as suggested by @chrk) or do `close(STDOUT_FILENO)` instead of `fclose(stdout)`, or maybe you can also reassign to stdout a new value obtained from `fdopen`.

Comment: It does work using close(STDOUT_FILENO) but i don't really understand why. could you please explain me what changes?

Comment: It is a little bit tricky. `printf` is a higher level I/O function. It is using `stdout` which is a pointer to structure containing lower level I/O file descriptor (STDOUT_FILENO) for standard output. If you close stdout, printf does not work anymore. If you simply replace the file descriptor it continues working without realizing that it is writing to other file. Anyway, it is a trick and better approach may be the one proposed by @chrk and to use read/write functions for pipes.

Answer (score 2):

In the child process, you use `printf(3)` which tries to write to `stdout`.

If you want to write to pipe, you can use `write(2)`, just like you used `read(2)` to read from it for the parent process.

Answer (score 1):

Use dup2.  You are assuming that dup is returning 1, but you have no way of knowing that.  Also, since you've already closed stdout, the call to printf is probably failing.  Check the return value. Instead of fclosing stdout, you can close the underlying file descriptor, but that's not good practice.